# user permissions in Amazon Linux: root vs ec2-user

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux

In an Amazon Linux instance, after deployment using ElasticBeanstalk, all the files are owned by `root` user:

```
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root 4096 jan 01 00:00 var
```

But the current user is `ec2-user` so I don't have permissions to create/modify inside `/var` folder anything. What is the best approach to make it work? `chown` and modify owner to `ec2-user`? add user to a user group if exists which I don't know... any other idea?

Comment: It is by design in Linux that only root can write to system locations such as /var. It's unclear why you need to be able to do that as a regular user.

Comment: Ok... just trying to install some packages, it throws: `Could not write file "/var/app/current/yarn-error.log"`

Comment: posted a solutins which tells you different ways on how to solve your issue.

Comment: You need to use sudo if they are system-wide packages. Typically you install node modules into the `node_modules` directory of a project instead.

Comment: Thanks @JatinMehrotra, but these workarounds are not valid, the use of sudo is not a recommended approach in this case

Comment: It is not recommended to change/edit existing folders/files in /var. Nevertheless I see no problem creating a new folder for your needs - eg for some special logging. The main question is your purpose and also if eg the application runs with root or has its own user/group. Maybe some more info would be helpful, what you want to do. I assume you have sudo. `sudo su -`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have permissions to create/modify inside /var folder anything.

you can use following ways to achieve this.

- Try sudo [your command]
- sudo chown user directory
- sudo bash //this will make your root directly

**But beware for 2 and 3 way, it can break your system if you do something wrong.There is a famous saying hope you know what you will do**